# MS SQL2005 Query/Stored Proc Results To Text using SqlCommand or any other method

Tags: sql-server-2005, text

I have a simple question.

I need to return results as simple text, either as a string or similar.

i.e. I want the same behavior such as

Results to Text (Cntrl + T)

When you run a Query from SQL Server Management Studio.

How can this be done programmatically against calling a Stored Proc from C#?

i.e. similar to `ExecuteReader();` or `ExecuteXMLReader();` but returning a string instead.

Is there some `ToString()` available?

Thanks,
Kai.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to build the sting yourself by reading from dbreader.

Comment: What do you mean by "dbreader"? I looked in system.data.sqlclient and system.data.common namespaces but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: i meant System.Data.Common.DbDataReader which is base of all DataReaders(sql, oracle, etc) in .Net